# Visual Studio Debugger bug on AND-assignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm encountering what seems to be a bug in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger. I have a simple piece of code in which a `bool` variable initialized to `true` is [AND-assigned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx) with an expression that evaluates to `false`. Its final result should obviously be `false`, but the debugger sometimes displays it as `true` instead.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 20;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 8;

    bool b = true;
    b &= x == y || x >= z && y >= z;
}
```

[image: b remains true]

The issue doesn't occur consistently; for example, if I substitute the `int` variables for their actual values in the AND-assignment, `b` correctly shows up as `false`. The issue doesn't manifest either if I reference the variable later (such as `Console.WriteLine(b)`).

I understand that the entire code snippet above is eligible for dead code elimination by the compiler, but I assumed that such liberties were not permitted when compiling in Debug mode and running with a debugger attached?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional with SP1, targetting .NET Framework 4.0 (although I have 4.5 installed), building in Debug mode for "Any CPU" (using a 64-bit platform).

Comment: Any chance at all you're editing the source while debugging?  In this case an off by 2 error in displayed line would cause b to be true.

Comment: @ebyrob: Not possible; VS 2010 doesn't allow changes to 64-bit applications while running.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't remember for "Any CPU".  I thought you might still be able to edit and continue in a 32-bit executable on 64 bit OS.  So this is a 64 bit executable?  PS what if you add e.g. `x=1;` below and run to that?  I've known running to `}` to be notoriously flakey.

Comment: @ebyrob: I assume so.

Comment: you're the one debugging it!  Are you stepping through your DLL (or module) attached to someone else's executable?

Comment: @ebyrob: It's a console application consisting of just the above code snippet. And the issue manifests even when the snippet is followed by other code which I continue to step through.

Comment: I guess you're right it's strictly platform.  I see the same on my 64-bit setup for x86, x64 and AnyCPU builds.  On my 32-bit machine b is false.  (Took a bit to get my 64-bit rig back to running)  Interestingly Release actually shows b false as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Bug #655793:  Misreporting of variable values when debugging x64 code with the Visual Studio 2010 debugger

seems related:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655793/

The bug's workaround also seems to work for this problem:

```
bool b = true;
b &= x == y || x >= z && y >= z;
// ...
bool c = b; // adding intermediate initialization of c fixes b as well.
```

One question would be whether this problem exists in VS 2012, since bug #655793 is marked fixed there.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the closest reported issue.